# How to merge same long lat points with different data into a unique one?

Tags: qgis, merge

I have a layer where there is more than 1 feature for a same object. Imagine i have  a layer called signals. There can be up to 10 features in the same place (long/lat) for a unique signal but the features can have different fields or not. I want to traspose (ms access term) those fields from vertical to horizontal (1 unique row). Is this possible in QGIS?

Imagine the following geographic features:

```
Feature 1               
Long    Lat   Field1    Field2  Field3
x        y    a         b       c


Feature 2               
Long    Lat   Field1    Field2  Field3  
x       y     a         b       d
```

What i need is to obtain:

```
Feature             
Long    Lat   Field1    Field2   Field3_1   Field3_2    
x       y     a         b        c          d
```

Is this posiible in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

It's a not an obvious question, so I split it in two parts:

1. Getting a Shapefile with unique point features and fill every field with all encountered values for each point (I'll post an image below to explain it better); and,
2. Splitting a field into several fields.

I wrote a Python script to solve 1., and, if you agree, I'd suggest that you post another question to address 2.

You can see in the image two layers loaded into QGIS. In the "source" point layer I've reproduced your scenario (upper table at the image). The "transposed" layer is the result of the script (bottom table at the image). The "source" layer has 8 points distributed in 2 different locations (1 location for points with id 1-6, and another location for points with id 7,8). I've added 3 fields with several values. Note that repeated values are kept as one value, whereas different field values are joined using a separator. The result, as you would expect, consists of only 2 points with all the different field values.

[image]

To test the script, open QGIS (I've used QGIS 2.6.1) and load only your source layer. Open the QGIS Python Console, copy the Python script and run it by pressing Enter a couple of times, until you see the new layer in the Table of Contents.

You can specify the fields you want to merge in the first line of the script. They must be text fields (numeric fields won't allow you to join values). By specifying the fields to merge, you can leave out other not so important fields, such as the `id` in the example. The value preserved for the `id` field (in the example) is the value of the first point visited while the script is iterating.

```py
fieldNames = ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3']
separator = ';'
dictFeat = {}
dictNewFeat = {}
layer = iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]
fieldIndexes = [layer.fieldNameIndex(fn) for fn in fieldNames]
fields = layer.pendingFields()
outFields = [fields[i].name() for i in range(len(fields))]

# create layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "transposed", "memory")
vl.startEditing()
pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField(c.name(),c.type()) for c in layer.dataProvider().fields()])

iter = layer.getFeatures()
for f in iter:
    attrs = f.attributes()
    geom = f.geometry().asPoint()
    if geom not in dictFeat: # Add a feature and copy attrs 
        dictFeat[geom] = attrs
        fet = QgsFeature(vl.featureCount()+1)
        fet.setGeometry(f.geometry())
        fet.setAttributes(attrs)
        pr.addFeatures([fet])
        dictNewFeat[geom] = fet.id()
    else: # Check if attrs are different
        if attrs != dictFeat[geom]:
            for i in fieldIndexes:
                if attrs[i] != dictFeat[geom][i]:
                    iter2 = vl.getFeatures()
                    tmpFet = None
                    for f2 in iter2:
                        if dictNewFeat[geom] == f2.id():
                            tmpFet = f2
                            break
                    oldValue = tmpFet.attributes()[i]
                    valueList = oldValue.split(separator)
                    if not attrs[i] in valueList:
                        pr.changeAttributeValues( {dictNewFeat[geom]: {i: separator.join([separator.join([str(e) for e in valueList]),attrs[i]]) }} )

vl.updateExtents()
vl.commitChanges()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

The missing part of the story (which I've called 2.) consists in splitting single fields into multiple fields, but please, open another question, that would help you get more help.

Let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to save your shapefile as a .csv file and edit the data in your favourite spreadsheet programme (I use Microsoft Excel). This is a simple layer saved as a csv and opened in Excel:

[image: Before editing]

I then edited it to look similar to your required layout:

[image: After editing]

And then add the csv file back into QGIS via the *Add Delimited Text Layer* option under the *Layer* menu. You can then check the attribute table to see if it looks correct:

[image: Added into QGIS]

Hope this helps!

Comment: the problem comes when you have thousands of elements...

Comment: Yes...I can see how that can be a problem if you have many features. There are spatial-join tools available (such as **Join Attributes by Location**) but this would only work if each feature had a unique layer which again is not suitable. I think the alternative would be to develop a python script in QGIS in which case hopefully others can help you with.